# How can I create subdomains on my main domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As you all know few sites offer feature which let you specify what type of url you would like to have. Mostly they are of type:

```
ABC.somedomain.com
DEF.somedomain.com
```

(Mostly these sites are blog/genealogy site.)

I do not quite understand how does it all work. How can I achieve this? Also, how can I test this on localhost to really see if all is working fine?

Comment: This is generally done through a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) host/service (many registrars -- e.g. the place where the domain name was purchased -- also provide DNS services). Otherwise, talk to the admin for the [local] nameservers being used, if it applies. In any case, this is off-topic.

Comment: What youi do in IIS (if thats where you host it) is that you create a new website within IIS and put in the host name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is very important, an you will need a DNS mapping for the domain, and an IIS (or whatever web-server) mapping for the domain/subdomain (or alternatively: a wildcard mapping).

As part of adding the IIS mapping, you also need to decide whether those two domains are in the *same* IIS application, or 2 *different* applications. Different applications may be easier to configure (especially if they point to different folders on disk, with different configurations), but a shared application (multi-tenancy) can be more efficient in terms of fewer app-startups, etc. Of course, it helps if you've designed for multi-tenancy from the start, in terms of cache key names, configuration data, etc.

Comment: But these things are automated. Also, I do not actually want to createa subdomain. I want that whatever is typed before my domain, it should be caught by my website. Internally I want only one website. But the user should be under the illusion that his website is on different subdomain.

Comment: @Anthony - then you are going to need to host your own DNS server with dynamic subdomain capability. If you don't want to have to reconfigure IIS, then that is where the wildcard mapping comes in, as that will catch all traffic sent to the IP (to any host). But ultimately your.com and foo.your.com and bar.your.com are ***3 different hosts***. You can't change the nature of the internet just by hoping...

Answer (score 1):

Buy a domain from a provider such as godaddy or namecheap.  Login to the cpanel (yourdomain.com/cpanel) and add a subdomain.  Make sure your hosting provider (shared, vpn, ect...) allows subdomains to be added.

Comment: I want these to be automated and I actually don't want to create subdomain. Only the visitor should feel so.